# Run ActiveRecord commands on Rails console without SQL caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to know if there is a way to disable SQL caching temporarily on Rails console.

I am running ActiveRecord commands on Rails console to see how long each queries take. But I cannot get a correct measure because Rails is caching the SQL and my queries seem to be happening almost instantaneously.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can remove it FROM the console but I think you can add this to an initializer to remove it for development.

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Rails.configuration.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache
end
```